# Reverse lookup for a sorted merged list

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given k sorted lists with comparable elements, where no two elements are equal, we could merge them into a new sorted list L by various algorithms. My question is, given the position of an element in this hypothetical list L, what is an efficient (better than merging and sorting) algorithm to output the list of an element and its position therein.

I also would be happy to know relevant keywords.

Given are only the k sorted lists and the position an element would have in list L. But L should not be created, and in particular is not given.

Comment: @tobias_k if I understand well, given two lists `a=[1,3,5]` and `b=[2,4,6]`, then `L=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Searching for L's 3rd element (0-indexed) should return b and 1

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not know in which list the element is, you will have to check each of the lists until you find it. But since those lists are sorted, you can make this lookup faster using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

- given merged list `L`, and `k` original lists `l_1` through `l_n` and index `x`
- for each `l_i`  the `k` original lists

  - perform a binary search to find `L[x]` in `l_i`
  - if you found the element, return the list `l_i` and the position of `L[x]` therein

The total complexity of this algorithm would be about *O(k log n)*, with *n* being the average number of elements in the *k* original lists.

If you have to repeat this for many values of `x`, it might pay to convert the `k` original lists to [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) first. This will need *O(k n)* of work up-front to create the sets, but then only requires *O(k)* for each `x` due to the *O(1)* lookup in sets.

Comment: I probably worded my question poorly. The point is that I don't have the list L, so I can't lookup its element. I'm only given the position and the k lists.

Comment: @vuur Yes, seems like I misunderstood the question and your answer to Aaron's interpretation...

Comment: This answer is essentially correct. If you replaced the `L[x]` references with something like "the xth element in the combined lists."